# dictionary append another dictionary to specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary I would like to append to another dictionary's `HIGHSEVERITY` key.

```
vulnsBySeverity={"HIGHSEVERITY":"", "MEDIUMSEVERITY":"", "LOWSEVERITY":""}
for result in json_object['results']:
    for vuln in result['vulnerabilities']:
        if vuln["severity"] == "high":
            print("Its high!: {}".format(vuln))
            vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"].update(vuln)
```

However, when I run this last line, it gives me an error of:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'
```

What I'm looking to do is append the value of `vuln` (a dictionary) to the dictionary key `vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"]` but getting that error? Note this dictionary `vulnsBySeverity` will have more than `1` `vuln` that I'm attempting to append to the `HIGHSEVERITY` key.

Comment: Do you want to save value of ```vuln``` to dictionary by key ```HIGHSEVERITY```?

Comment: If you want use ```HIGHSEVERITY``` as dict then initialize it as ```"HIGHSEVERITY": {}```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.update()` method is applicable to a `dict`, but `vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"]` is a string (from the initialization)

In your case, you don't need this method i think. A simple `=` should do the trick:

```
vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"] = vuln
```

If multiple `vuln` may have a "high" priority, you could think of using a list too:

```
vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"] = []

for result in json_object['results']:
    for vuln in result['vulnerabilities']:
        if vuln["severity"] == "high":
            vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"].append(vuln)
```

Take care of mutability in these cases, if you're modifying vuln after the assignments. (Use `vuln.copy()` in this case)

Note:
As mentionned in your comments, you can initialize `vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"]` to use `.update()` but this won't work if multiple `vuln` have a "high" priority (Only the last one will be taken into account. Previous ones will be overwritten because of the update)

Note:
You can use list comprehension too, if you use the list solution:

```
for result in json_object['results']:
    vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"] = [vuln for vuln in result['vulnerabilities'] if vuln["severity"] == "high"]
```

Comment: It still amazes me how powerful list comprehensions are. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value of the dictionary `vulnsBySeverity` is an empty string. string type has no `update` method. I think a dictionary of lists would be better. And append the `vuln` dictionaries to the list like below.

```py
vulnsBySeverity = {"HIGHSEVERITY": [], "MEDIUMSEVERITY": [], "LOWSEVERITY": []}

for result in json_object['results']:
    for vuln in result['vulnerabilities']:
        if vuln["severity"] == "high":
            print("Its high!: {}".format(vuln))
            vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"].append(vuln)
```